# c# Need help trying to put in and run two loops for the same input

Tags: c#

I've put in a loop with Try.Parse so that if the user enters a decimal number, the program will ask them to enter another number until they put in a integer and then the program will carry on with the next part. 
However what i'm struggling with is putting in another loop that makes it so that the user can only enter a number between 1 and 100, and if they don't there should be an error message that loops until they do enter this. Id like them to run at the same time and i have this one, but i want it to also check whether its in the range and i'm not sure how to do that.
I'm new to programming so I'm not great at this. 
Thank you in advance!

```
        string inputcost;
        string inputmoney;
        int validcost;
        int validmoney;
        int changereq;

        Console.Write("Please Enter The Cost, In Pennies, Of The Item You Have Purchased: ");
        inputcost = Console.ReadLine();
        bool result = int.TryParse(inputcost, out validcost);

        while (!int.TryParse(inputcost, out validcost))
        {
            if (result == true)
            {
                Console.Write("Valid Value");
            }
            if (result == false)
            {
                Console.Write("Please Enter A Valid Integer Value");
                Console.WriteLine();
                inputcost = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that the `result` variable you're looking at is only written once: outside the loop.  Consider trying something like the following pseudocode (a `do-while` loop works exactly the same as a `while` loop, except it always gets executed once before the condition is checked):

```
bool validInput;
do
{
    // If you set it true to begin with, you can set it false on any unmet conditions
    // If it doesn't get set false, you've got a valid input and can exit the loop.
    validInput = true;

    Read input from user
    Check if it's a valid integer, if not print message and validInput = false
    Check if it's between 1-100, if not print message and validInput = false;
} while (!validInput);
```

Then if you want to tackle something more advanced, look at the [`continue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx) keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to use a method and do something like:

```
Console.Write("Please Enter The Cost, In Pennies, Of The Item You Have Purchased: ");
inputcost = Console.ReadLine();

bool result = false;

while (!result)
{
  result = checkNumber();
}

public static bool checkNumber()
{
  if(inputcost < 1 || inputcost > 100)
  {
    Console.Write("Please Enter a valid value: ");
    inputcost = Console.ReadLine();
    return false;
  }
  else
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
string inputcost;
    string inputmoney;
    int validcost;
    int validmoney;
    int changereq;       

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Please Enter The Cost, In Pennies, Of The Item You Have Purchased: ");
        inputcost = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!(valuecost >=1 && valuecost <=100))
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter value between 1 and 100.");
        }

        bool result = int.TryParse(inputcost, out validcost);                      

        if (result == true)
        { 
            Console.Write("Valid Value");
        }
        if (result == false)
        {
            Console.Write("Please Enter A Valid Integer Value");
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
string inputcost;
string inputmoney;
int validcost = 0;
int validmoney = 0;

Console.Write("Please Enter The Cost, In Pennies, Of The Item You Have Purchased: ");
inputcost = Console.ReadLine();
// only accept integers
while (!int.TryParse(inputcost, out validcost))
{
  Console.Write("Please Enter An Integer Value: ");
  inputcost = Console.ReadLine();
}
// valid integer input in variable validcost 
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
  Console.Write("Enter an integer between 1 and 100: ");
  inputmoney = Console.ReadLine();
  if (int.TryParse(inputmoney, out validmoney))
  {
    if (validmoney > 0 && validmoney < 101)
    {
      done = true;
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid input: " + inputmoney);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input: " + inputmoney);
  }
}

  //validcost is an integer and validmoney is an integer between 1 and 100
  Console.WriteLine("validcost: " + validcost + " validmoney: " + validmoney);
  Console.ReadKey();
```