# c# cant run two functions in a loop?

Tags: c#

What i want to do is to make it that inside a loop, the computer checks whether the number entered is firstly not a decimal, and at the same time i want to make sure that the number is within the range 1 - 100. My code now works in regards to having the first function about the number not being a decimal, so when i enter a decimal, an error message is displayed that tells the user to keep adding another number until an integer is added, and it then runs to the next part. However it doesn't seem to work when i put in a number outside of the range, the error message doesn't pop up and the conditions just don't seem to work. What i want to know is how do i get these two parts, the decimal and the range checking to work simultaneously. I'm really new to coding so could any explanations be simple so that i could understand. Thank you in advance!

```
        string inputcost;
        string inputmoney;
        int validcost;
        int validmoney;
        int changereq;

        Console.Write("Please Enter The Cost, In Pennies, Of The Item You Have Purchased: ");
        inputcost = Console.ReadLine();
        bool result = int.TryParse(inputcost, out validcost);

        while (!int.TryParse(inputcost, out validcost))
        {   

            if (result == true )
            {                    
                Console.Write("Valid Value");
            }
            if (result == false)
            {
                Console.Write("You Cannot Enter Decimals. Please Enter A Valid Integer Value.");
                Console.WriteLine();
                inputcost = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (validcost < 100 && validcost > 1)
            {
                Console.Write("valid value");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("invalid value.please enter a number between 1                      and 100 ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You enter the while loop only when the user types something that cannot be converted to an integer. If it is a valid integer you never execute the code inside the loop.

Comment: wow! Same answered question?  [c# Need help trying to put in and run two loops for the same input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166017/c-sharp-need-help-trying-to-put-in-and-run-two-loops-for-the-same-input) what are you asking for? The answer is in the link... what is wrong with the answer?

Comment: Same person, same question, new account... seems like misuse.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I agree. Different user name, same question with parts of MY posted answer, but not my whole answer which works.

Comment: Sorry guys, didn't understand the answers given and needed to ask again but i had already asked too many questions on the other account apparently. To be honest i still don't really understand the answers. I'm new to coding and this website. @HimBromBeere

Comment: is there a way i could speak to you about this problem, like a chat option, as i'm still confused. @HimBromBeere

Comment: Of course you get a ban if some moderator gets this abuse and this is totally ok. You shoud ask clear questions, clearify it further if some comments on it appear that ask you to do so and ask for further explanation if you don´t understand an answer. Posting the same question again is not an option, you should explain why the already posted solution didn´t work for you.

Comment: Apologies i know now then, wont happen again. Can i message you on something else about this question? @HimBromBeere

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
while (!int.TryParse(inputcost, out validcost))
```

means that you enter the while loop only when the user types something that cannot be converted to an integer. If it is a valid integer the code inside the while loop is never reached and thus, your test on the valid range is never executed

Instead put everything inside the an infinite loop and provide a way to break the program (type x to quit)

```
while (true)
{   
    Console.Write("Please Enter The Cost, In Pennies, Of The Item You Have Purchased: (type x to quit)");
    inputcost = Console.ReadLine();

    // Check if the user wants to stop executing the program
    if(inputcost == "x") 
        break;

    // Check if it is a valid integer 
    bool result = int.TryParse(inputcost, out validcost);
    if (!result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You Cannot Enter Decimals (or strings). Please Enter A Valid Integer Value.");
    }
    else if (validcost > 100 || validcost < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("invalid value.please enter a number between 1 and 100 ");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Valid value");
        // other code block that works with the input number....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly use another condition for your loop, something that first checks for an integer and afterwards if it is in range:

```
while (!int.TryParse(inputcost, out validcost)) || validCost < 1 ||  validCost > 100)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer between 1 and 100");
    inputCost = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

All the code that should be executed when your inout is valid should now gow *beyond* the loop, not *inside* it.